# Running 2 asynchronous ember tests in the same test method

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

How do I run this in the same test? Right now I need to run them separately.

```
test('Props tests', function () {

  var controller = this.subject({
    model: createMock()
  });

  controller.set('foo', false);
  controller.set('foo2', false);
  equal(controller.get('baa'), true);

});


test('Props tests', function () {

  var controller = this.subject({
    model: createMock()
  });

  controller.set('foo', true);
  controller.set('foo2', true);
  equal(controller.get('baa2'), true);

});
```

I think I need to wrap some code in an Ember.run function statement.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you should wrap your `controller.set`s in `Ember.run`.

```
Ember.run(function() {
    controller.set('foo', false);
    controller.set('foo2', false);
});
equal(controller.get('baa'), true);
```

You should be able to have consecutive `equal` assertions as long as you don't change the state of the subject (without using `Ember.run`).